# Texstudio do not hint in ubuntu 18.10 (Don't see preferred command)

Tags: texstudio, editors, auto-completion

I am using texstudio in ubuntu 18.10, but i can't see the preferred command when i typing. In Windows 10, i still see it but ubuntu is not? Please give me the solution to solve this problem?

Comment: The best welcome to tex.stackexchange.

Comment: Have a look into the "completion" tab of your texstudio preferences. Which options do you have activated there?

Comment: In this tab, i use default settings of texstudio, active all check box and preferred command set is typical. On below box, active latex-dev.cwl, latex-document.cwl, latex-mathsymbols.cwl and tex.cwl